# Process annotations with RetentionPolicy.SOURCE in a maven mojo

Tags: java, maven, annotations

Is it possible to (in any way) process the annotations with `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` (or at least `RetentionPolicy.COMPILE`) in a maven Mojo?

I'd like to generate an additional documentation based on my custom annotations with aforementioned retention policy – since the documentation is in no way needed during runtime, I wouldn't like these annotations to clutter the ClassLoader.

(something like *swagger*, but I need not to serve this documentation during runtime and swagger annotations *are* retained at runtime...)

The reason I don't want to use a simple `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` is that I want to have the convenient configurability of a full-fledged maven plugin, with a lot of optional properties etc.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you're after.

https://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/docs/usage.html

I'm looking for the same thing, but this plugin isn't available at my workplace, so I can't really comment further. Seems to meet your use case though.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>process</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <configuration>

            <processors>
               <!-- list of processors to use -->
               <processor>org.bsc.apt.BeanInfoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </processors>

          </configuration> 
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, unless I am mistaken, the `maven-processor-plugin` is just a way of running `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` instances during compilation, and I do not want to do that because it would force me to pass the configuration as _system properties_ (`-Dkey=value` type of thing) or something like that and I do not like this. I would like to create my own maven plugin altogether so that I may have great configurability with tens of options (and lists of them, and nested options etc.) instead of simply passing some key-value system properties.